# Approach for creating Database connection

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am developing a program, which reads files from local machine and uploads it's data into Oracle database server. This program is to be executed every 2-3 minutes through scheduler with average of 2-3 input files for each run. 
I would like to know approach I should take to create database connection so that it would create minimum performance impact.

Thanks,

Best Regards,
Kunal

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use connection pooling, it allows physical database connections to be reused by multiple logical connection instances, which are temporary handles to the physical connection. Use a connection pool data source to return a pooled connection, which is what encapsulates the physical database connection. Then use the pooled connection to return JDBC connection instances (one at a time) that each act as a temporary handle. Below is the sample of Oracle connection pooling.

```
...
OracleConnectionPoolDataSource ocpds = new OracleConnectionPoolDataSource();

ocpds.setDriverType("oci");
ocpds.setServerName("dlsun999");
ocpds.setNetworkProtocol("tcp");
ocpds.setDatabaseName("816");
ocpds.setPortNumber(1521);
ocpds.setUser("scott"); 
ocpds.setPassword("tiger");

PooledConnection pc = ocpds.getPooledConnection();

Connection conn = pc.getConnection();
...
```

Comment: Hi Jigar, How will this act when next instance runs before earlier has completed? Will it lock the table ?

Comment: Connection pooling is a bunch of pre-established connections. If the previous connection is still in use, then it takes the another connection from the pool. Once the connection task is over and it gets ideal for pre defined seconds. Ex. 30 seconds. The connection moved back to pool. In configuration, you can define the number of connection you want in pool, their ideal time etc.

Comment: A `ConnectionPoolDataSource` is not a connection pool (or: it isn't supposed to be one)! It is only the datasource **for** a connection pool implementation (which would hold instances of `PooledConnection` obtained from a `ConnectionPoolDataSource`).

Answer (score 0):

In the case of Oracle you should look at the Universal Connection Pool, UCP. See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e12265/toc.htm for detailed information.

You basically use:

```
PoolDataSource  pds = PoolDataSourceFactory.getPoolDataSource();
pds.setConnectionFactoryClassName("oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource");
pds.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE");
pds.setUser("<user>");
pds.setPassword("<password>");
pds.setInitialPoolSize(5);
Connection conn = pds.getConnection();
```

Comment: Hi Mark, As the duration between run is small, I am worried about its behavior when a second instance is started before first's completion. Is there any way by which I can have control over it ? something like semaphore?

Comment: @user4280951 Concurrency is already handled by the connection pool itself.